# search large file for an array of IP addresses

Tags: perl

I have a large network file of about 400MB. I have an array of about 11 IP addresses.

I need to search the entire file for these 11 IP addresses but my Perl script is not working. I have put the ip addresses in an array but I'm not sure if I want to open the file for each element of the array or vice versa.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @leaflogicservers = qw/
xx.117.189.181
xx.117.191.238
xx.117.185.80
xx.117.184.255
52.xxx.52.29
52.xxx.52.183
52.xxx.52.184
52.xxx.52.185
52.xxx.52.186
40.xxx.190.72
40.xxx.11.156
/;

my $PathToFile = 'router01.log';

open my $router01, '<', "$PathToFile" or die $!;


while ( my $ip = <$router01> ) {
chomp($ip);
for my $catch ( @leaflogicservers ) {
chomp($catch);


if ( $catch =~ m/$ip/ ) {
print "Caught!\n";
}
}
}
```

Comment: Create a regex out of `@leaflogicservers` and compile it. That way you'd only need to search through the big file once. Btw, your current approach seems to just search through the file once too (only looping over `@leaflogicservers` manually instead). What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: One problem: You have `.` in your regex so it may get hits on IP:s you didn't intend it to match. You'd better escape all those `.`s.

Comment: There are more efficient ways but I can't see what's wrong with what you show?  What are those `x` -- are they really in the file? What are some representative lines from a file, verbatim? Show a first few that you think should match some of these `leaflogicservers`.

Comment: um, switch that around: `if ($ip =~ /$catch/)` (want the `$catch` to match the line not the other way round) ... still, what you show should work if a line in a file has only the ip as one of the shown ones.  If there are extra spaces on the line then `$catch =~ /$ip/` will NOT work since the spaces in `$ip` (the line) don't exist in `$catch` -- but the correct `$ip =~ /$catch/` would still work, since `$catch` should match the part of `$ip` other than the spaces.

Answer (score 5):

You could search for all of them at once.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my @leaflogicservers = ...;

my $pat = join "|", map quotemeta, @leaflogicservers;
my $re = qr/\b(?:$pat)\b/;

while ( <> ) {
   say "Found $&" if /$re/;
}
```

`perl`'s regex engine uses a trie for nontrivial alternations of constant strings, so this is very efficient and factoring out common prefixes would not help.

The `\b` fixes a bug in your code. For example, your code incorrectly matches `152.xxx.52.29` because your list includes `52.xxx.52.29`. This prevents that.

`quotemeta` fixes another. You were using `.` (matches any character other than LF) instead of `\.` (matches a `.`).

---

If the file consists entirely of LF-terminated IP addresses, a hash would be faster than a regex.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my @leaflogicservers = ...;

my %leaflogicservers = map { $_ => 1 } @leaflogicservers;

while ( <> ) {
   chomp;
   say "Found $&" if $leaflogicservers{ $_ };
}
```